# extract data from two databases postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have two database , test1 and test2

in test1 I have a table named : emplyee

in test2 I have a table named : user_

I want to extrat the users from table employee  who are not exist in the table user_

I try with this query

```
select * from employee where mail_employe not in

( select emailaddress from test2.user_ )
```

I have this error :

```
ERROR:  schema "test2" does not exist
LINE 3: ( select emailaddress from test2.user_ )
```

I try also with this syntax :

```
select * from employee where mail_employe not in

(SELECT emailaddress from dblink('dbname=test2','SELECT emailaddress FROM user_'))
```

I have also this error

```
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
LINE 3: (SELECT emailaddress from dblink('dbname=test2','SELEC...
```

**updated**

I try to user the systax of SCHEMA

in the two database I have this code of SCHEMA

```
CREATE SCHEMA public
  AUTHORIZATION postgres;

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO public;
COMMENT ON SCHEMA public
  IS 'standard public schema';
```

I try to use this code without success

```
 select * from test1.public.employee where mail_employe not in

    (SELECT emailaddress from test2.public.user_')
```

but i have the same error

Comment: Why you not using two shema instead of two databases? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html

Comment: I try to use the systax of SCHEMA , but I have also the same error

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
CREATE SCHEMA sch1;
CREATE SCHEMA sch2;
CREATE TABLE sch1.foo ( id serial, name varchar );
CREATE TABLE sch2.bar ( id serial, title varchar );
```

Query:

```
SELECT sch1.foo.name, sch2.bar.title 
FROM sch1.foo 
   INNER JOIN sch2.bar on sch1.foo.name = sch2.bar.title;

SELECT sch1.foo.name 
FROM sch1.foo 
WHERE sch1.foo.id IN (SELECT sch2.bar.id FROM sch2.bar);
```

Unfortunately, as long as you don't change search path you need to write full path to resources.